# Doctrine caching configuration

Tags: php, doctrine

In the doctrine docs, it looks like I need the configuration object available for metadata caching:

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Configuration;
use Doctrine\Common\Proxy\ProxyFactory;

// ...

if ($applicationMode == "development") {
    $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache;
} else {
    $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache;
}

$config = new Configuration;
$config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
$driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver('/path/to/lib/MyProject/Entities');
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);
```

However, this is currently inside a module in the zend directory in composer, so I cant change it. Id like to hand the option to do this in the array configuration:

```
return array(
    'doctrine' => array(
    'connection' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'params' => array(
                'pdo' => new PDO("connection details")
            ),
            'query_cache'=>new PhpFileCache(), //<- like this
            'metadata_cache'=>new PhpFileCache(), //<- and this
        ),
    ),
),
```

I know this is possible because I have done it once before, however, **I cant seem to find this method on the docs anymore**. The current docs show the setup for YAML.

Answer (score 0):

I can set up many connections in the Doctrine entity manager, but I supply one configuration since this sets up things that run once for the lifetime of that run, or if we have a cache installed such as APC, the lifetime of that release.

I achieve this by adding the info to $config['doctrine']['configuration'], not $config['doctrine']['orm_default/your_connection']['configuration']

```
return array(
'doctrine' => array(
    'connection' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'params' => array(
                'pdo' => new PDO("connection")
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'configuration' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'metadata_cache' => 'filesystem',
            'query_cache' => 'filesystem',
            'result_cache' => 'filesystem'
        ),
    ),
),
```